# cannot find symbol (Location location) - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been successfully running my project in an emulator until I encountered this error. I have not installed any package I know of that will cause this error. I have searched online in an attempt to get a solution for it but all my effort has proven futile.

Comment: If you are on windows, maybe move your project into the root of C drive. Could potentially be a character length constraint. Otherwise, run flutter clean, and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am using a mac machine. flutter clean did not help

Answer (score 0):

First of Fall, did you install dart and setup check not then install and setup environment for that and check because I have found the same issue when I plugging the flutter.

Comment: OP said that he had been successfully running the project. He wouldn't be able to do that if dart was not installed.

Comment: I have installed dart and as I said, I have been running the project until now. Also, I am able to run other flutter projects in vs code.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed a package (places_service) that executes Geolocator files whenever the application is initiated. That was the cause. If anyone is facing such an issue, take a look at your packages and test them one after the other.